# Mapreduce Job running in local mode instead of cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

Configuration are done for running mapreduce job in cluster mode on top of yarn but its running on local mode.
Not able to figuring out whats the issue.

below is yarn-site.xml (at master node)

```
    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
            <value>namenode:8031</value>
    </property>
     <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>    //node manager servi
            <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>    //This will specify that how mapper reducer work
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
            <value>namenode:8030</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
            <value>namenode:8032</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
            <value>namenode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
            <value>2042</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
            <value>false</value>
    </property>
```

yarn-site.xml (at slave node)

```
    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>    //node manager service
            <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>    //This will specify that how mapper reducer work
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
            <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
            <value>namenode:8031</value>    //Tell the ip_address of resource tracker
    </property>
```

mapred-site.xml (at master node and slave node)

```
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
            <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
            <value>2048</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
            <value>2048</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
            <value>2048</value>
    </property>
```

on submission the job output is like below.

```
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local1556004420_0001
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local1556004420_0001
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1556004420_0001_m_000000_0
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://namenode:9001/all-the-news/articles1.csv:0+134217728
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
18/12/06 16:20:43 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
18/12/06 16:20:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1556004420_0001 running in uber mode : false
18/12/06 16:20:44 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/12/06 16:20:49 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
18/12/06 16:20:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 1% reduce 0%
18/12/06 16:20:52 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
18/12/06 16:20:55 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
18/12/06 16:20:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 2% reduce 0%
18/12/06 16:20:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
18/12/06 16:21:01 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
18/12/06 16:21:02 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 3% reduce 0%
18/12/06 16:21:04 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
```

Why it's running in local mode. 
I am running this job on 200MB file with 3 nodes 2 datanode and 1 namenode.

etc/hosts file is as shown below

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       anil-Lenovo-Product

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

192.168.8.98 namenode
192.168.8.99 datanode
192.168.8.100 datanode2
```

[image: YarnUI image]

Comment: Please show your /etc/hosts files

Comment: yeah sure but really not able to figure it out where is the problem..

Comment: Other than having `The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/`, what exactly is the issue you're having? Are you able to go to the YARN UI? Does it show there is more than one NodeManager active? The data might just be processed from one datanode, despite being replicated... Adding datanodes doesn't scale processing, only storage. You would need to add NodeManagers

Comment: Yes can access my yarn UI and also it is showing me 2 nodes but when I start Job then Yarn UI doesn't show me that job has been submitted or any job is running but at backend the job is in running state. 2 NodeManagers are running and Yarn UI showing them active but still when I run job then output is localRunner map...

Comment: Attached YarnUI image. In this image if I submit job even then apps running are shown 0.

Comment: Hmm... Your XML looks fine. And as long as that's copied over both machines, should be fine as well. They are clearly registering with the ResourceManager, so I'm not sure why the apps wouldn't be submitted through them... Perhaps try `yarn jar` instead

Comment: Yes I tried yarn jar and XML are copied to nodes...even in log file also there is no error.

Comment: Its gotta be something between the YARN and Mapred site, but I would personally suggest using Ambari to reinstall Hadoop because it has sensible defaults and a management UI

Comment: Ambari is new to me but okay I will try this..its really a weird problem...I restart the yarn but again the same problem is occurring...okay thanks for possible solution...

Answer (score 0):

1. first check if these configurations are effective: 
   http://{your-resource-manager-host}:8088/conf by default or
   your configured UI address: http://namenode:8088/conf
2. then make sure these properties are configured:

   in mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}</value>
  </property>
```

in yarn-site.xml

```
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
```

restart YARN service and check if it works.

jobs are submitted by ClientProtocol interface, and one of its two implementations are created when service started:

- **LocalClientProtocolProvider** prefix with job_local
- **YarnClientProtocolProvider**  prefix with job_

according to MRConfig.FRAMEWORK_NAME(value is  "mapreduce.framework.name") configuration, and its valid options are `classic`, `yarn`, `local`.

Good luck!